# Sharepoint 2010 migration - document library contains only the latest 2 versions of the doc

Tags: sharepoint-2010, versioning, sharepointdocumentlibrary

After migrating a sharepoint application from a MOSS 2007 environment to SharePoint 2010, the document library which had versioning enabled is showing only the last two vesrsions of the documents. The remaining versions are missing!

What could be the problem here? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify the Document Version settings for the document library?  There are settings that let you enable versions but limit the number of versions kept.

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing i checked, but there were no limit set to the number of versions to be kept.

Comment: just thinking, maybe set these values, save it and return them to the desired settings.